# File uploads working on Lambda function, but not on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint to upload images to my website:

```py
from uuid import uuid4

import boto3
from fastapi import APIRouter, File, HTTPException, Request, UploadFile
from loguru import logger

from app.core.config import ImageRouterConfig


def upload_image_to_s3(file: UploadFile, bucket_name: str, cloudfront: str) -> str:
    s3 = boto3.resource(service_name="s3")
    filename = f"{uuid4()}{file.filename}"
    s3_key = f"images/{filename}"
    try:
        file.file.seek(0)
        s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(
            Fileobj=file.file,
            Key=s3_key,
            ExtraArgs={"ContentType": file.content_type, "ACL": "public-read", "ContentEncoding": "base64"},
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Could not upload file.") from e
    return f"{cloudfront}/{s3_key}"


def create_images_router(config: ImageRouterConfig) -> APIRouter:
    router = APIRouter()

    @router.post("")
    def post_upload_file(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)) -> str:
        logger.info(f"Uploading file {file.filename}")
        logger.info(f"Request headers: {request.headers}")
        logger.info(f"Content type: {file.content_type}")
        s3_url = upload_image_to_s3(file, config.bucket_name, config.cloudfront_url)
        return s3_url

    return router
```

and it is behind a lambda function. The endpoint works fine when I try it on the lambda endpoint, but when I try it behind my proxy API Gateway function, the image is not uploaded correctly.

Lambda result: https://cgtimages.mcleanmarine.com/images/5412df15-75e9-4f8e-8124-c26177f1f4beScreenshot 2024-03-05 203922.png

API Gateway result: https://cgtimages.mcleanmarine.com/images/a62d5a58-db1b-49c9-baf4-04cf4947ccc7Screenshot%202024-03-05%20203922.png

The logged headers look pretty much the same,

API Gateway:

```
{
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryW3QR6whxq5UADBJ2",
    "dnt": "1",
    "host": "cgtapi.mcleanmarine.com",
    "origin": "https://cgtapi.mcleanmarine.com",
    "referer": "https://cgtapi.mcleanmarine.com/docs",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"111\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-65f0c8e8-1803357a69b673c9697b2b10",
    "x-forwarded-for": "5.69.131.93",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
}
```

Lambda:

```
{
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-length": "3574",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9O1wkVqbquByAPm8",
    "dnt": "1",
    "host": "n6qpkmpc6gtzlkxfw3q4yuryye0edlfj.lambda-url.eu-west-2.on.aws",
    "origin": "https://n6qpkmpc6gtzlkxfw3q4yuryye0edlfj.lambda-url.eu-west-2.on.aws",
    "referer": "https://n6qpkmpc6gtzlkxfw3q4yuryye0edlfj.lambda-url.eu-west-2.on.aws/docs",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"111\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "x-amzn-tls-cipher-suite": "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "x-amzn-tls-version": "TLSv1.3",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-65f0c93b-1ce14a2c22a726664a955bf5",
    "x-forwarded-for": "2a02:c7c:730b:e800:e54a:21cc:d942:5779",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
}
```

So I am not sure why this is not working.

How can I make this endpoint work beind API Gateway?

Edit:

I have just noticed that the API gateway is not adding the "content-length" header

Comment: Note that API Gateway and Lambda have payload limits (10MB and 6MB respectively).

Comment: @jarmod The lamba function is uploading images bigger than I will need to upload (example: https://cgtimages.mcleanmarine.com/images/de84364f-20ae-48cf-89ff-1e70a4f941baScreenshot%202024-03-06%20215412.png) so its not the payload limit of the lambda function thats causing my issue :(

Comment: OK, just wanted to be sure you knew those limitations. You haven't added much detail of what the failure is (and links to external images are out of scope for Stack Overflow, especially when they're not actually accessible) so please include details in the post.

Comment: you image links are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that API Gateway is configured to support binary media types. Go to your API Gateway settings and add */* (or specifically image/jpeg, image/png, etc., depending on your requirements) to the binary media types. This tells API Gateway to treat these types of payloads as binary, which is crucial for file uploads.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

> To handle binary payloads for AWS Lambda proxy integrations, you must
> base64-encode your function's response. You must also configure the
> binaryMediaTypes for your API. Your API's binaryMediaTypes
> configuration is a list of content types that your API treats as
> binary data. Example binary media types include image/png or
> application/octet-stream. You can use the wildcard character (*) to
> cover multiple media types. For example, */* includes all content
> types.

Comment: I added `multipart/form-data` as well as `image/jpeg`, `image/png`, `*/*` and `/*/*` to my api gateway binary encodings but I am still getting the same error